# Define query in talend context using tSystem component

Tags: talend, impala

I am trying to run an impala command using the tSystem component in Talend Studio. I am able to run the command in terminal .

```
impala-shell -i hostname:21000 -d default -k --ssl -q "COMPUTE STATS DEFAULT.TABLENAME;"
```

I tried to apply the same command in tSystem component. so, the command in TOS will be appied by this way:

In Talend context:

```
 hostname = hostname:21000
    database = default 
    tablename = default.tablename
```

Impala command I defined in tSystem component:

```
"impala-shell -i context.hostname -d context.database -k --ssl -q "COMPUTE STATS context.tablename;""
```

However, I got an error for this line -> `-q "COMPUTE STATS context.tablename;"`

Error:
[image]

Is there any ways I could use the string query in my impala command using tSystem component in TOS? Appreciate any helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to concatenate the context variables with your query string:

```
"impala-shell -i " + context.hostname + " -d " + context.database + " -k --ssl -q \"COMPUTE STATS " + context.tablename + ";\""
```